# What type to set an OracleParameter for an output variable?

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

Our DB admin gave me the following code to run for a package he created:

```
Declare
MT        MY_PACKAGE.MET_TBL;  --- This reads the record layout defined in the  Package
Begin
    MY_PACKAGE.MY_PROC(inParam => 50, outParam => MT);
End;
```

In Oracle it appears that its a type of record.

```
 TYPE DATA_REC is Record( --- fields...);
 TYPE MET_TBL IS TABLE OF DATA_REC INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
```

My question is what type do I set for the output variable?

I don't seem to see an equivalent type in OracleDbType.

Here is my code...

```
    var inParam = new OracleParameter("inParam", OracleDbType.Int16, 150, ParameterDirection.Input);
    // What type should I use??
    var outParam = new OracleParameter("outParam", OracleDbType., ParameterDirection.Output);

    var result = context.Database
                .SqlQuery<MyTest>("BEGIN MY_SCHEMA.MY_PACKAGE.MY_PROC(:inParam, :outParam); end;", inParam, outParam).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use type `OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray`, see [PL/SQL Associative Array Binding](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/featOraCommand.htm#BABBDHBB)

However, for output values you should prefer RefCursor data type, see [PL/SQL REF CURSOR and OracleRefCursor](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/featRefCursor.htm#ODPNT309)

Comment: Thanks.  I initially called a SP and a package (2 separate tests) where the output was in a cursor.  However it was taking me 14 seconds to bring back 50 records.  We were wondering if the cursor was adding unnecessary overhead.